# cannot update mysql table with php

Tags: php, mysql

Cannot update my table with the follow code...have been trying for hours...
**tagboard** is the table name, **mytag1** is what I want to update with reference to **emailadd**.

```
$myemail = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["myemail"] );
$mytag1 = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST["mytag1"] );
echo $mytag1;
$query = "UPDATE tagboard SET mytag1='{$mytag1}' WHERE emailadd = {$myemail}";
$result=mysql_query($query);
```

OR

```
$sql="UPDATE tagboard SET mytag1 ='".$_POST['mytag1']."' WHERE  myemail='".$_POST['myemail']."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: `mysql_error()` is your friend

Comment: Yes can you please post the errors you are getting?

Comment: @mikeB thanks! --- This is my error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com' at line 1"  What am I suppose to do?? I will google it but if you already know.....

Comment: You're not quoting your variables.

Comment: And I caught a few more errors... I called the column tag1 not mytag1 in the table, but I am sending mytag1....Just started learning php recently. Sorry for being stupid. And many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add quotes around your email address field in the query:

```
$query = "UPDATE tagboard SET mytag1='{$mytag1}' WHERE emailadd = '{$myemail}'";
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)) It works for me! Have been figuring this out for a while now

Answer (score 0):

You have this line:

```
$query = "UPDATE tagboard SET mytag1='{$mytag1}' WHERE emailadd = {$myemail}";
```

Try putting single quotations around the email variable too

```
$query = "UPDATE tagboard SET mytag1='{$mytag1}' WHERE emailadd = '{$myemail}'";
```